# Android application development: java vs. jquery mobile

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery-mobile

I'd like to build an android application for a school project but I'm a bit confused, I saw that i can build an application using Java or using Jquery mobile.

Do they have the same capabilities?

If i build an application using Jquery , can i pack it and have it installed like a java application (as apk) or is it only used for building websites?

If so, what tool do i use to pack it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery Mobile needs an intermediary framework that communicates between JavaScript and Java. [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com) is a popular one of these frameworks.

PhoneGap is also actively maintained and they roll out new versions almost every month.

The main reason to use PhoneGap/jQuery Mobile is that it makes development easy if you already know HTML/JS/CSS. Another great reason to use PhoneGap is that you can use your existing website as the base for native applications, yeah, plural, not just Android but also iOS, Blackberry, etc. It also gives you a pre-built UI with some widgets so you don't have to roll your own.

The jQuery Mobile documentation talks about [some of the caveats to creating a native application with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html).

Comment: PhoneGap also has some downsides: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/03/multi-platform-frameworks-destroy.html

Comment: The author of that article offers their opinion without backing-up with any facts. I certainly agree that using native code will create a smoother user experience but `The obvious fact is that the hybrid approach does not bring the best features of mobile web apps and native apps but instead the worst` is certainly an opinion (with which you may agree the article does not support this).

Comment: The only other thing I'd say about that article is that the author basically points out issues that are not related to the product but to the way a very select group of developers has used the product. I don't think that stating the rating on Google Play for a single app. says anything useful about the platform on which it has been built. Also the bullet point list for why multi-platform apps won't work is addressed by a myriad of plugins.

Comment: You are right, the author is quite biased and I wouldn't agree on the worst combination of web and native part either. It's also no problem to find bad native apps. Probably even more since it's harder to create a nice native app than using the hybrid approach. But once you add an abstraction layer you will loose some details. If not then you loose the benefits of that abstraction. Especially when you try to abstract hardware / UI / API / etc. differences. Native apps can achieve higher quality but they need more resources (time, platform knowledge, ..) to get to the same level of a hybrid app

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have already tried or what your skill set is (based on your stackoverflow history you may know more about java than I do), but you would be best off just using the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/index.html). I was able to design and complete a custom business project and learn java while doing it. I can't comment much on jQuery since I've never used it. jQuery seems like it might be a nice for the reasons Jasper listed but might add layers of complexity you don't need to deal with if you don't need to run your app on other platforms.

Comment: I actually know java very well and also Jquery/css/html, and i can tell you that it is much easier to build an application using the latter.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I'll take a stab at Jquery/css/html the next time I need to do an Android project.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Mobile Framework provides the way how you web application looks on different hand held devices simply but this can not use the native device capabilities like picking up an contact from the contact book/application. while native application has the capabilities to handle all the system generated events or broadcasts.